# Открыть OpenFileDialog по заданному пути

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы `OpenFileDialog` открылся в проводнике
в нужном мне месте? Как задать этот путь?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У `System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog` есть свойство [`InitialDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Если это свойство установить перед показом, диалог откроет указанный в нём каталог. (Если сможет, конечно...)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно свойство [`InitialDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Официальный пример:

```
var ofd = new OpenFileDialog()
{
    InitialDirectory = "c:\\",
    Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*",
    FilterIndex = 2,
    RestoreDirectory = false // true если хотите, чтобы диалог запоминал
                             // последний каталог, в который перешёл юзер
};

if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // можно работать с файлом
```

Comment: @Владимир: Пожалуйста! Вам стоит принят ответ kff, он был на минуту раньше.